# Ordering of fields in describeSObjects result

Tags: soap-api, describesobject, describesobjectresult

Is there any ordering to the fields in the describeSObjects result? We're using the `connection.js` file from [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_connecting.htm). The [DescribeSObjectsResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) does not seem to mention any particular ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guaranteed order in the documentation, although the order does appear to be deterministic (e.g. it should be the same way for an org for a specific API version every time).